# Selenium: Is it possible to launch browser without installing it

Tags: selenium

I am wondering if I can launch the browser without that browser already being installed. The environments I work on comes with very old firefox browsers and it won't be feasible to update it everytime.

Answer (score 3):

You needn't to install that browser, just download portable version of that browser and set main executable of browser in your test.

Example:

```cs
    FirefoxBinary binary = new FirefoxBinary(new File("path_to_bin"));
    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(binary, profile);
```

Comment: I am having selenium jar version 3.141.59. I tried as below but it didn't work. 

FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.setBinary("/home/user1/Downloads/firefox/firefox-bin");
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions(); 
driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);

I also tried System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", "/usr/local/bin");

Comment: Is there any error message? You can try add your firefox folder to PATH variable.
Here is an guide to adding folder to PATH: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-add-directory-to-path-in-linux/

Comment: Getting the exception:                   
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting 45 seconds for Firefox to start.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'den01chv', ip: '10.196.14.151', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.1.12-37.4.1.el6uek.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
 at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.XpiDriverService.waitUntilAvailable(XpiDriverService.java:247)
 at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.XpiDriverService.start(XpiDriverService.java:159)